# How to search a meta for a tag on the main site?

Tags: support, tags, search

For example, there is an [exception](/questions/tagged/exception) tag on Stack Overflow.  I can search Stack Overflow for questions tagged with [exception](/questions/tagged/exception) by searching "tag:exception".  However, on *Meta* Stack Overflow, there are questions about the [exception](/questions/tagged/exception) tag.  These questions are not tagged with the [exception](/questions/tagged/exception) tag, since they are on the meta site.  How do I search the *meta* site for questions about the main site [exception](/questions/tagged/exception) tag?

Comment: Did you try [`[tags] exception`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btags%5D+exception)? It is a bit high on false positives but it is only 65 posts ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since using the markdown `[tag:exception]` on Meta Stack Overflow creates a link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exception, you can search for

```
url:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exception
```

[This search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2Ftagged%2Fexception) currently gives 5 results:

[image]

It'll miss instances where people aren't using the tag markdown, e.g. like this:

> When you use the [exception] tag, make sure ...

(I usually do that in comments, where `[tag:exception]` doesn't work.)

Answer (score 2):

The on site search is a bit *less optimal* with attempts like [`[tags] exception`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btags%5D+exception) and [`title:exception`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aexception).

With a [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/1063431?tagname=exception) that check all revisions of the raw markdown for the markup `[tag:exception]` the results becomes much better:

[image]

Keep in mind SEDE is only updated once a week, on Sunday morning. If you're new to SEDE do checkout the [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) and visit [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede) to say Hi.