# Is there a way to search for a question (or an answer) that mentions a tag?

Tags: support, tags, search

I see some questions (but mostly answers) that mention tags. For example I could mention the [burrito](/questions/tagged/burrito) tag here.

Is there a way I could search for posts that have mentioned a particular tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For cases where you're on a child meta site (e.g. Meta Stack Overflow) and you want to search for posts mentioning a main site tag, you can just [search for e.g. `url:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exception`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2Ftagged%2Fexception), as I mentioned [in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329351/295232).

That doesn't work for Meta Stack Exchange, cases where the `[tag:]` syntax is used on a main site, or where `[meta-tag:]` is used on a child meta site. Searching for `url:https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burrito` will find my answer (because I literally mention the link) but fail to find your question. However, there's a neat trick for this: you can search for [`url:/questions/tagged/burrito`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%2Fquestions%2Ftagged%2Fburrito):

[image]

It will find posts where people directly linked to the [tag page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burrito) as well; I don't think those can be filtered out easily. You can use [other search options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=help) to e.g. limit the search results to questions only with `is:q`.

---

The obvious way, searching for the full URL with `url:https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burrito` doesn't work in this particular case, because the `[tag:burrito]` element is rendered as `<a href="/questions/tagged/burrito" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;burrito&#39;" rel="tag">burrito</a>`, which uses a *relative* URL.

Comment: Awesome! I would never have thought of that.

Comment: It took me a few educated guesses to get the syntax right as well. In fact, I was already writing a horribly slow SEDE query to search for the literal occurrence of `[tag:burrito]` in the markdown.

Comment: Heh, it turns out I answered a [pretty similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329351/295232) 6-8 weeks ago. It *is* slightly different, though, funny to see how the post rendering works in detail.

Comment: @Glorfindel I think this answer is far more detailed. Perhaps close the other one as a dupe?

Comment: That makes sense, but I should first edit the details in the other answer into this one, I guess.

Comment: Seem that solution works for tag substring, not a full tag. For instance [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%2Fquestions%2Ftagged%2Fstatus) gives me post with any `status*` tag.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ you're right, and using double quotes doesn't help: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22%2Fquestions%2Ftagged%2Fstatus%22 (and the hyphen in `status-*` is not to blame, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22%2Fquestions%2Ftagged%2Fstatus-rev%22)