# How can I find posts with tags in the body?

Tags: support, tags, search

Is there a way to find the posts with tags in the body (not the questions tagged with specific tags)?

I mean when post body contains tags written in a form of `[tag:tag-name]` and displayed as a clickable element like this one [tag-name](/questions/tagged/tag-name).

P.S. I don't tag this post with [tag-search](/questions/tagged/tag-search) since description of that tag doesn't fit the purposes of my question.

BTW: answer from the linked post [searches for substring](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331716/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-a-question-or-an-answer-that-mentions-a-tag#comment1206797_331734) not a full tag.

Comment: See here: [Is there a way to search for a question (or an answer) that mentions a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331716) and [How to search a meta for a tag on the main site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329351)

Comment: Probably only with SEDE: https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1381537

Comment: This seemed to work for me `\[tag\:` I knew there were a lot of such posts on [ell.meta.se] Here are the results: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5C%5Btag%5C%3A

Comment: @ColleenV I didn't know escaping special chars worked in search. That is pretty neat.

Comment: @ColleenV it seems that your search request is broken. Not all posts from result contains a tag.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Example? Did you look at the answers or just the questions? Because the sampling I did all had it somewhere in the thread.

Comment: @rene I find a lot of bugs by just trying what I think is the obvious way to do it. For example, if I want to add `is:q` to the search I have to do it before the escaped string, so I may not have the escaping quite right. I may not need the extra backslash before the `:` Just questions would be: `is:q \[tag:`

Comment: @ColleenV just check the search results from your link from the end (page 30 when 15post/page).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Yeah, if you sort by relevance, the end of the search results aren't exactly what you asked for. That's true of any search on SE - the results are a bit fuzzy. If you're using SEDE the results are much more exact, but not as timely. Non-SEDE searches aren't for counting the number of posts that match a specific pattern if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you put the tag name in there, it seems to provide more exact results. It may be an artifact of the escaping (and the `:` does need to be escaped): `\[tag\:grammar\]` : https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5C%5Btag%5C%3Agrammar%5C%5D

Comment: There does seem to be some weirdness with the escaping after experimenting with it a bit more. It's probably not intended to work that way and might be exposing an issue in the code used to sanitize search strings.

Comment: This may work though: `url:*/tagged` The escaping of individual characters causes problems, but a wildcard should work if you aren’t looking for a specific tag. (you probably want to make the pattern a little more specific to exclude urls that aren’t for SE).

Comment: @Glorfindel I'm not sure that we have to leave this question opened. Both questions are the same.